# send array of integers from the server to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have an array:

```
     let numbers = [8,4,2,1,7,5,3,0];
```

I want to send this array to the client using socket.emit.
But when i send this data using:

```
   var numbers1 = JSON.stringify(numbers);
  socket.emit('new',{num:numbers1});
```

And listen it on the client side using:

```
 socket.on('new',(data)=>{
    var aa = data.num ;
   console.log(aa);
  });
```

It says undefined on the DevTools for the console of aa.

## Edit

I had written an incomplete code.
  The complete client side code is:

```
   socket.on('new',(data)=>{
var numbers = JSON.parse(data.num); //this will retrieve your array.
console.log(numbers);
```

});

It says as the error

```
  VM42:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

which means the data which is trying to parse is undefined.

Comment: And whats `data` ? Might log that...

Comment: You most likely need to use `JSON.parse(data)` on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen because you have used JSON.stringify, so you must do JSON.parse to the "**data**" object to access the property "**num**" of the object sent to the client.

```
socket.on('new',(data)=>{
   var aa = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log(aa.num);
});
```

Comment: yeah, that is one of the errors, but the other one is that he is trying to send an object
`{num:numbers1}`
so it is parsing the `numbers1` but he is not parsing the object that he is sending.

Answer (score 0):

what you should do when emitting is the following:

```
let numbers = [8,4,2,1,7,5,3,0];
var numbers1 = JSON.stringify(numbers);

socket.emit('new',{num:numbers1});
```

and then you should listen on the other side like this:

```
socket.on('new',(data)=>{
    var numbers = JSON.parse(data); //this will retrieve your array.
    console.log(numbers);
});
```